# Що означає слово "приведенниця"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

На [Порталі української мови та літератури](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) знаходжу відмінювання цього слова. Однак, аби з’ясувати саму семантику слова, звернулася у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryvedennycja), однак там його не виявилося.

Отже, що означає слово "**приведенниця**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це слово знаходимо у [Словнику української мови за ред. Б.Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F):

> **Приведенниця**, ці, ж. Дочь жены, рожденная ею отъ перваго мужа и приведенная въ семью второго. Ум. Приведе́нничка.
>
> Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 3. — С. 408.